# Is there a class of probability density functions includes the laplacian and the normal pdfs?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Is there a class of probability density functions that includes the Laplacian and the Normal pdfs?

$$f(x\mid\mu,b) = \frac{1}{2b} \exp \left( -\frac{|x-\mu|}{b} \right)$$
and
$$f(x \mid \mu, \sigma^2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2} } e^{ -\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} }$$
seem very connected via some p for $p=1$ and $p=2$.

Is there a canonnical way to do this?

Maybe something like
$$f_{\sigma, p} =\frac{1}{n(p)\sigma}\exp\left(-\left|\frac{x}{m(p)\sigma}\right|^p\right)?$$

I got the intuition that $n$ might be something along the lines of
$$n(p) = \sqrt{2} p \Gamma(\frac{p+1}{p}),$$
but I can not figure out the appropriate $m$
and this is mainly speculation.

Comment: "but I can not figure out the appropriate m" Sorry but what do you mean by "appropriate" here? One can choose any nonzero $m$ one likes...

Comment: I do not think that is true, since the $m$ has to play nicely with $n$ s.t. $f_{\sigma, p}$ is a pdf (integrates over $\mathbb{R}$ to 1).

Comment: Pfff... Yes, of course, once $p$ and $m$ are fixed, there is only one suitable $n$ (depending on $p$ and $m$, which makes impossible  the formula you suggest). And once $p$ and $n$ are fixed, there is only one suitable $m$. Again: what do you call "the appropriate $m(p)$"?

Comment: Sorry, by appropriate I meant suitable.

Comment: And again, **one can choose any $m(p)$ one wants**, this only multiplies $n(p)$ by the relevant factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, such a class is called generalized normal distribution.
Please have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_normal_distribution).

A PDF from this class has the form :

$$f(x)= \frac{\beta}{2\alpha\Gamma(1/\beta)} \; e^{-\left(\frac{|x-\mu|}{\alpha}\right)^\beta}$$

With :

- $\alpha$ and $\beta$ strictly positive real numbers,
- $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$,
- $\Gamma$ the Gamma function.

As you can see, for $\beta=1$, we have a Laplacian density function. And for $\beta=2$, we have the Normal one.